# Mention the complex number with given condition on the place

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

How do i mention the set of complex numbers on the plane that satisfy the condition

$$\arg(iz-1)= \frac \pi 3$$

I tried to assign $u=iz-1 $ then $\arg(u)= \pi/3$, but I don't know how to continue this.

Comment: Find $\arg(iz-1)$, when $z = a+ib$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we need

$$\arg(iz - 1) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$\arg\left(i(z + i)\right) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$\arg (i) + \arg(z + i) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2} + \arg(z + i) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$\arg(z -  (-i)) = -\frac{\pi}{6}$$

On the Argand diagram, this is actually a half-line originating from $(0, -1)$ subtending an angle of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ radians below the positive-horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your thoughts
$$
\eqalign{
u &=i z-1  \rightarrow \cr
iu &= -z-i  \rightarrow \cr
z &= -iu-i  \cr
}
$$
So since the image of $u$ in the Argand diagram is the the ray from $(0,0)$ and forming angle ${\pi \over 3}$, the transformation $z = -iu-i$ rotates this image by $arg(-i)=-{\pi\over 2}$ and translates this image by $-i$.
Thus is the ray starting from $-i=(0,-1)$ and forming angle ${\pi\over 3} - {\pi\over 2} = -{\pi\over 6}$.